# Remove bash formatting in text using python

Tags: python, bash

I'm having text file containing data from bash output, so it contains formatted data, more specifically, color codes like this:

```
[0;31m16521[0;0m [0;32mDesktop/business-models-for-data-economy.pdf[0;0m
```

I want to strip down the formating, that is, get it in plain text:

```
16521 Desktop/business-models-for-data-economy.pdf
```

While I understand it is kinda like removing chunks starting with `[`, containing `;` and ending with `m`, I would like to know if there is a clearer, more correct way of doing this.

Comment: NB. it is likely the `[`are preceded by an ESC char (0x1b)

Comment: @jsbueno I see - can you elaborate on this please? or better even - a reference?

Comment: Any chance that output was generated by `ls`?  If so, is `--color=yes` passed to that `ls` command somehow?  These escape codes look a lot like the how `ls` colors different file types.

Comment: Like @DigitalTrauma says, the correct way is not to remove the ANSI escape codes, but to not print them in the first place. Is this from running `somescript > file` or from e.g. a `script` transcript?

Comment: You are correct, but I have no control over this execution.
The question is very specific, it concerns data (in file) containing bash formated output, which I need to convert to plain.

Comment: @vonPutresh: these are ANSI text color and attribute (bold/italic/underline) setting coddes - there is a nice reference here: http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code <- is actually more complete. The formalism make sit harder to read: "CSI" means the byte "27" (hex 0x1b) for the ESC character.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a regex:

```
import re

s = '[0;31m16521[0;0m [0;32mDesktop/business-models-for-data-economy.pdf[0;0m'

new_s = re.sub(r'\[.*?;.*?m', '', s)

>>> print new_s
16521 Desktop/business-models-for-data-economy.pdf
```

### Demo

Comment: See other comments - the concern is the NB character as well. Also, I tend to avoid regexes as much as possible.

Comment: This case cries for regexps all over the place - just check the table I linked into the question comments, and check if the ESC characters are in your files: they will make the regexp(s) less ambiguous.